# Exception when release resources from bitmap used for dynamic PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, aforge

I want to use less amount of RAM as possible- using Windows forms and Aforge.Net to capture video. 
Problem is that when i try to for example ".Dispose()" some elements I got exception:

```
    static void Main()
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Main");
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());  <----- here VS showing me an exception (An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll)
    }
```

Code that do this:

```
    public void setLocalCamera(string cameraName)
    {
        videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(cameraName);
        videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
        videoSource.Start();
    }


    Bitmap bitmap;
    private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (bitmap != null) 
            bitmap.Dispose(); <--- here is the problematic code

        bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pB_Camera.Image = bitmap;

    }
```

This code make for random time exception (I have no idea what exactly fire it). I also tried some other solutions that i found but nothing work/help (like make bitmap.Dispose() after pB_Camera.Image = bitmap; but this also make an exception)

How I can fix this issue and release as much RAM as I can?

Comment: You have to dispose the *old* bitmap, the one you no longer need.  Not the one you are going to display.  So simply use if (pB_Camera.Image != null) pB_Camera.Image.Dispose();

Comment: When I try your code I got the exception in the same place:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Object is currently in use elsewhere.

Comment: You can set first `pB_Camera.Image` to `NULL` and then dispose the bitmap and reassign it to `pB_Camera`.

Comment: I add something like this on beggining:  pB_Camera.Image = null;if (bitmap != null)   bitmap.Dispose(); I do not saw any errors and RAM usage is around 100 mb (OK). But there is small issue. every few random seconds I noticed that on the bitmap blink white image (not image from camera).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct sequence that avoids both exceptions and flickering is:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
void SetBitmap(Bitmap value)
{
    pB_Camera.Image = value;
    if (bitmap != null) bitmap.Dispose();
    bitmap = value;
}
```

and the usage is simple:

```
private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    SetBitmap((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone());
}
```

EDIT: However, your concrete case is slightly different because the event is raised on a non UI thread. Although a simple `Control.Invoke` will work, if the frame is used just for display, I think it would be better to implement a little "single item producer/consumer" non blocking pattern, in order to let the worker thread continue processing while you are consuming the image, like this:

```
private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    PushNextFrame((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone());
}

Bitmap nextFrame;

void PushNextFrame(Bitmap value)
{
    var prevFrame = Interlocked.Exchange(ref nextFrame, value);
    if (prevFrame != null)
    {
        // previous frame has not been consumed, so just discard it.
        // no need to notify the consumer, because it should have been done already.
        prevFrame.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        // previos frame has been consumed and we just set a new one, so we need to notity the consumer.
        BeginInvoke((Action)OnNextFrameAvailable);
    }
}

Bitmap PullNextFrame() { return Interlocked.Exchange(ref nextFrame, null); }

void OnNextFrameAvailable()
{
    DisplayFrame(PullNextFrame());
}

Bitmap currentFrame;

void DisplayFrame(Bitmap value)
{
    pb_Camera.Image = value;
    if (currentFrame != null) currentFrame.Dispose();
    currentFrame = value;
}
```

Comment: For now i testing this solution but I change   [pB_Camera.Image = value;]->       this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {pB_Camera.Image = value; }); as there is the same exception as @up "Object is currently in use elsewhere". This make a static ram Usage (52.6) and for now no errors. I do not thought that I will need to use invoke method in main Form1 where this object exist. I will still make tests to be sure that everything is ok with this solution. If there is any other better solution or my is wrong please tell me. I will check everything.

Comment: Now I will check your 2nd option. For now its ok (just slight more RAM usage-but not much). I will update this topic if all my tests will be positive or I will find some other issue.